# Load Multiple SVG file in Snap.svg will conflict?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Here's the problem. I'm trying to make some SVG animation with Snap.svg. I use some pre-drawn svg assets.

I can load single svg file with snap without problem, but when I tried to load multiple svg files, the colors are all messed up.

I googled and tried different solutions, including loading them in separate svg elements, loading them one by one, pre-compile loaded svg with angular $complie.... but all of them simply not work :(

Anyone has any suggestions on what is wrong?

Here is the code snippet i use to load svg

```
    var s = Snap(target);
    var g = s.group();
    Snap.load("../assets/svg/"+part+".svg",function(f){
        g.append(f);
        g.drag();
        resolve();
    })
```

And this is my angular try

```
.directive('snap', ['$compile',
function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            var s = Snap(400,400);
            Snap.load('../assets/svg/'+attrs.part,function(f){
                s.append(f);
                elem.append($compile(s)(scope));
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Please Help, Thank you!

All SVG files are generated by illustrator

Comment: I would try and isolate it to two minimal files, and then put them on a jsfiddle to look at, without the angular stuff.

Comment: @lan https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/407